# Firebase Authentication UI - Hint Color (Android)

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Please forgive me if this is answered elsewhere - I have been searching/testing/experimenting for 2 days without much luck.

I need to change the hint color for the email/password fields.  Whether I'm on Light or Dark mode on my emulator, the text in the hint shows up Black:

[image]

... until I click on the field and it becomes at least readable:

[image]

Here's my theme as it stands right now:

```
   <style name="Theme.MyApp.FirebaseAuth" parent="FirebaseUI">
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/onboard_background</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/gk_orange</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/gk_orange</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/gk_orange</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/gk_orange</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/gk_orange</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gk_orange</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/gk_orange</item>
        <!--<item name="hintTextColor">@color/gk_orange</item>-->
    </style>
```

I've tried creating a style with parent="FirebaseUI.TextInputLayout.EmailField" and other similar things - but nothing seems to touch that hint color.

If someone could please point me in the right direction, I'd be most grateful.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you use material components?

Answer (score 1):

While the answer from codearn19 did not work directly as suggested, it did inspire an experiment that ultimately solved my issue.  Note that this solution is probably more "global" than some people might like, in that it changes ALL the TextInputLayouts under FirebaseUI, but for my purposes, it works:

```
    <style name="FirebaseUI.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gk_orange</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>
```

This allowed me to change the hint color. The @null was necessary to maintain the original look & feel of the rest of the TIL.

Thanks all!!!

Comment: This worked pretty well for me also, my only gripe at the moment is there is no outline around the field at all now. Working on a solution for that currently

Answer (score 0):

According to [This GitHub Post](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/229#issuecomment-236868365) you can try changing the style of `FirebaseUI.EditText` such as:

```
<style name="FirebaseUI.EditText">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>

<style name="FirebaseUI.Text.TextInputLayout" parent="@style/FirebaseUI.EditText" />

<style name="FirebaseUI.Text.HintText" parent="@style/FirebaseUI.EditText" />
```

The general theme used from this snippet was:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_login</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```